# Why does the Ratio Test prove that this particular sequence converges on 0?

Tags: real-analysis

I was recently reading *How to Think about Analysis* by Lara Alcock in preparation for taking Real Analysis in the winter, and ran into the following theorem regarding sequences that either tend towards infinity or converge on a particular number, specifically the Ratio Test.

> Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a sequence such that $(a_{n+1}/a_n) \rightarrow l$. Then:
>
> 1. If $-1 < l < 1$ then $(a_n) \rightarrow 0$.
> 2. If $l > 1$ and $a_n > 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $(a_n) \rightarrow \infty$.
> 3. If $l > 1$ and $a_n < 0 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $(a_n) \rightarrow -\infty$
> 4. If $l < -1$ then the sequence neither converges or tends to $\pm \infty$.
> 5. If $l = 1$ we get no information.

Two specific examples she gives of sequences that converge to $0$ are $$\left({n^2 \over 2^n}\right)$$ and $$\left({6^n \over n!}\right)$$

For the latter sequence, $$\left({6^n \over n!}\right) = {6 \over 1}, {36 \over 2}, {216 \over 6}, {1296 \over 24}, {7776 \over 120},\ldots$$

I can see for the ratios I test that that the ratios tend to get smaller over time, which isn't too surprising. For example, $${36 \over 2} \div {6 \over 1} = 3, {216 \over 6} \div {36 \over 2} = 2, {1296 \over 24} \div {216 \over 6} = 1.5$$

The author also gives the intuition of why this sequences approaches $0$ by pointing out that $${6 \times 6 \times\cdots \times 6} \over {1 \times 2 \times \cdots \times n}$$

This makes it intuitively obvious why this denominator grows much more quickly than the numerator, which makes it seem a lot more sensible why this should approach $0.$

So, I understand that the ratio between each two consecutive terms is decreasing (if I'm reading this correctly), which isn't too surprising, and I understand the intuition behind why this sequence approaches $0.$ However, I'm a little confused as to how this actually "meets" the first test given that I gave several examples where $(a_{n+1}/a_n) > 1$ - for example, ${36 \over 2} \div {6 \over 1} = 3$, which is obviously greater than $1.$ Naturally, *eventually* the ratio will be less than $1$, but doesn't the theorem kind of imply that the ratio of *any* two consecutive elements of the sequence will have a ratio greater than $-1$ and less than $1$?

Also, how does this account for sequences that converge on things other than $0$, $- \infty$, or $\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say that a sequence $\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to a limit $L$ is to say that, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n > N$ implies $|b_n - L| < \varepsilon$.

Rephrased into colloquial English: For any positive number $\varepsilon$, the sequence of those $b$-subscript elements *eventually* gets within $\varepsilon$ of $L$, and stays at least that close to the limit. The key word in this description is the same term that you italicized:

> Naturally, *eventually* the ratio will be less than $1$, but doesn't the theorem kind of imply that the ratio of any two consecutive elements of the sequence will have a ratio greater than $−1$ and less than $1$?

No, the theorem does not say this. The theorem's hypothesis is precisely that the sequence made from a ratio of consecutive terms converges to $l$, which means that *eventually* this sequence (i.e., these ratios) will be within $\varepsilon$ of $l$.

Comment: So, the fact that the ratios are decreasing is precisely the point in this case?

Comment: @EJoshuaS The key fact is that the ratios are *eventually* decreasing. Consider the sequence $1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, \ldots$. This is a decreasing sequence whose ratio sequence converges to $l = 1/2$ (in fact, the ratio is always $1/2$). And, indeed, the sequence converges to $0$. Now, consider the same sequence but beginning with $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$. The first five elements are, in fact, *increasing*; but, the overall behavior of the sequence is the same: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/8, \ldots \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Fair point - I guess there's no particular requirement as to exactly when or how quickly it converges (just as long as it eventually does), right?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Exactly.

Comment: One more point I'm a little confused about, then: in the sequences you point out and in the sequence my book pointed out, it seems like you could examine the sequence itself to determine its behavior (i.e. it seems clear just from looking at the sequence that they'll converge on 0) - are there cases that I haven't read about yet where it's easier to determine (or prove) what the ratio of the consecutive terms are converging on than it is to do the same thing for the sequence itself? Or is this more formalizing the intuition?

Comment: @EJoshuaS Formalizing the intuition for this particular case; note that you could have a sequence alternating between being halved and quartered, so that the ratio of terms does not converge to anything (it switches between $1/2$ and $1/4$, never settling on either) but the actual sequence will still converge to $0$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks - that's very helpful. I think I understand now.